# Qt: printscreen key in keyPressEvent

Tags: c++, qt, events, printing, screen

When I pressing keys, this code works, but not with Print Screen key.

```
void KeyHooker::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event->key();
}
```

**Q.** How can I grab Print Screen key?

Comment: This may help: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18610

Comment: @vahancho Good call you just beat me to it :J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the OS grabs this before it reaches your code: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18610/#90901

You'll need to use Microsoft's `LowLevelKeyboardProc` in your code to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx