# How to capture PrintScreen key in qt?

Tags: qt

The below code doesn't detect print_screen key for me.

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (Qt::Key_Print == event->key())
        qDebug() << "Print Screen pressed";
```

Comment: Same with my case. My guess would be that the operating system may have the Print Screen key reserved to itself, at least on Windows. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002328/qt-printscreen-key-in-keypressevent

Comment: It'`s impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: printscreen key in keyPressEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002328/qt-printscreen-key-in-keypressevent)